# mysql error code 1292

Tags: mysql, mariadb, errors, galera

We are running kea DHCP server with MySQL DB and today we encounter following error and after googling everyone saying it could be MySQL bug so wanted to see if it's really a bug or implementation issue.

MariaDB-server-10.2.15-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (3 node galera cluster)

```
2020-03-07 01:59:16.484 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/29796] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 00:0c:29:ae:77:cb], cid=[no info], tid=0x80b9c710: lease 10.10.10.22 has been allocated
2020-03-07 02:04:29.625 ERROR [kea-dhcp4.alloc-engine/29796] ALLOC_ENGINE_V4_ALLOC_ERROR [hwtype=1 00:19:85:f0:1c:89], cid=[no info], tid=0xd7790768: error during attempt to allocat
e an IPv4 address: unable to execute for <UPDATE lease4 SET address = ?, hwaddr = ?, client_id = ?, valid_lifetime = ?, expire = ?, subnet_id = ?, fqdn_fwd = ?, fqdn_rev = ?, hostna
me = ?, state = ? WHERE address = ?>, reason: Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-08 02:04:29' for column 'expire' at row 1 (error code 1292)
```

Comment: what type is the column `expire` - `SHOW CREATE TABLE lease4`? 10.2.15 is quite old and there [16 release fixes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-102-series/) of the 10.2 series.

Comment: may i know reason for down vote?

Comment: Don't worry about the down vote. Enough people think its good enough. Based on the answer, it wasn't something I thought about and was a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be a problem with daylight saving time: In the US (and possibly other places) the hour between 02:00am and 03:00am on 8th March 2020 does not exist because the clocks are moved forward one hour at 02:00am to 03:00am.

Comment: So it's mysql bug or something else?

Comment: @Satish - no, assuming you really are in the affected time zone, then it's not a MySQL bug. It might be a misconfiguration - perhaps your OS has a different time zone than the MySQL server? The question you have to ask yourself is: Why did kea DHCP server think that was the time, when that is a time that doesn't exist?

Comment: I believe OS automatically convert time no matter which TIMEZONE you live, I have `kea` running on `UTC` timezone and `MySQL` running on `EDT` timezone.

Comment: @Satish I'm no expert on this, but EDT observes DST whereas UTC doesn't. You may need to put them in the same time zone or do something else clever to ensure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Now i will put both of them in UTC but just trying to understand how things can wrong with daylight saving, i would love to run TEST in lab and see if i can reproduce this error.

Comment: I did into logs and strongly believe it was daylight issue because this issue started 1am and 2am it got resolved itself based on logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.  That converts your system time into UTC for storing, then converts back when fetching.